# Rails Cocoon add field link not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cocoon-gem

I am trying to dynamically add a field named URL from a table called addresses to  form for a table called essentials to a form using simple form. I am using the cocoon gem. I also have no experience with nested forms. My current error is undefined method *`input' for :address:Symbol*. I am using devise, foundation 6, rails 4 and simple form.

#### Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();
//= require_tree .
//= require cocoon
//= require global
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
```

#### global.coffee

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  addresses = $('#addresses')
  count = addresses.find('.count > span')

  recount = -> count.text addresses.find('.nested-fields').size()

  addresses.on 'cocoon:before-insert', (e, el_to_add) ->
    el_to_add.fadeIn(1000)

  addresses.on 'cocoon:after-insert', (e, added_el) ->
    added_el.effect('highlight', {}, 500)
    recount()

  addresses.on 'cocoon:before-remove', (e, el_to_remove) ->
    $(this).data('remove-timeout', 1000)
    el_to_remove.fadeOut(1000)

  addresses.on 'cocoon:after-remove', (e, removed_el) ->
    recount()
```

#### address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :essential
end
```

#### essentials.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :addresses

accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :essentials
  has_many :addresses
end
```

#### _address_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='fields'>
    <%= f.input :url %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove address", f %>
</div>
```

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @essential do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :band_name, placeholder: "Band Name" %> 
    <div>
        <%= f.input :years_active_start, placeholder: "Start" %>  <%= f.input :years_active_end, placeholder: "End" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :country, placeholder: "country" %>
    <h6>Studio Albums</h6>
    <%= f.select :studio_albums, options_for_select([ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12" ]){}, {} %>
    <%= f.input :band_members, placeholder: "Band Members" %>
    <%= f.select :genre, options_for_select([ 
        "Art Punk",
        "Alternative Rock",
        "College Rock",
        "Crossover Thrash",
        "Crust Punk",
        "Experimental Rock",
        "Folk Punk",
        "Goth/Gothic Rock",
        "Grunge",
        "Hardcore Punk",
        "Hard Rock",
        "Indie Rock",
        "Lo-fi",
        "New Wave",
        "Progressive Rock",
        "Punk",
        "Shoegaze",
        "Steampunk",
        "Anime",
        "Blues",
        "Acoustic Blues",
        "Chicago Blues",
        "Classic Blues",
        "Contemporary Blues",
        "Country Blues",
        "Delta Blues",
        "Electric Blues",
        "Ragtime Blues",
        "Children’s Music",
        "Lullabies",
        "Sing-Along",
        "Stories",
        "Classical",
        "Avant-Garde",
        "Baroque",
        "Chamber Music",
        "Chant",
        "Choral",
        "Classical Crossover",
        "Contemporary Classical",
        "Early Music",
        "Expressionist", 
        "High Classical",
        "Impressionist",
        "Medieval",
        "Minimalism",
        "Modern Composition",
        "Opera",
        "Orchestral",
        "Renaissance",
        "Romantic", 
        "Wedding Music",
        "Comedy",
        "Novelty",
        "Standup Comedy",
        "Vaudeville",
        "Commercial", 
        "Jingles",
        "TV Themes",
        "Country",
        "Alternative Country",
        "Americana",
        "Bluegrass",
        "Contemporary Bluegrass",
        "Contemporary Country",
        "Country Gospel",
        "Country Pop", 
        "Honky Tonk",
        "Outlaw Country",
        "Traditional Bluegrass",
        "Traditional Country",
        "Urban Cowboy",
        "Dance", 
        "Club / Club Dance", 
        "Breakcore",
        "Breakbeat/Breakstep",
        "Brostep", 
        "Chillstep", 
        "Deep House", 
        "Dubstep",
        "Electro House", 
        "Electroswing",
        "Exercise",
        "Future Garage", 
        "Garage",
        "Glitch Hop", 
        "Glitch Pop", 
        "Grime", 
        "Hardcore",
        "Hard Dance",
        "Hi-NRG/Eurodance",
        "Horrorcore",
        "House",
        "Jackin House",
        "Jungle/Drum’n’bass",
        "Liquid Dub",
        "Regstep", 
        "Speedcore", 
        "Techno",
        "Trance",
        "Trap",
        "Disney",
        "Easy Listening",
        "Bop",
        "Lounge",
        "Swing",
        "Electronic",
        "2-Step",
        "8-bit", 
        "Ambient",
        "Bassline", 
        "Chillwave",
        "Chiptune", 
        "Crunk",
        "Downtempo",
        "Drum & Bass",
        "Electro",
        "Electro-swing",
        "Electronica",
        "Electronic Rock",
        "Hardstyle",
        "IDM/Experimental",
        "Industrial",
        "Trip Hop",
        "Enka",
        "French Pop",
        "German Folk",
        "German Pop",
        "Fitness & Workout",
        "Hip-Hop/Rap",
        "Alternative Rap",
        "Bounce",
        "Dirty South",
        "East Coast Rap",
        "Gangsta Rap",
        "Hardcore Rap",
        "Hip-Hop",
        "Latin Rap",
        "Old School Rap",
        "Rap",
        "Turntablism",
        "Underground Rap",
        "West Coast Rap",
        "Holiday",
        "Chanukah",
        "Christmas",
        "Christmas: Children’s",
        "Christmas: Classic",
        "Christmas: Classical",
        "Christmas: Comedy",
        "Christmas: Jazz",
        "Christmas: Modern",
        "Christmas: Pop",
        "Christmas: R&B",
        "Christmas: Religious",
        "Christmas: Rock",
        "Easter",
        "Halloween",
        "Holiday: Other",
        "Thanksgiving",
        "Indie Pop",
        "Industrial",
        "Inspirational",
        "CCM",
        "Christian Metal",
        "Christian Pop",
        "Christian Rap",
        "Christian Rock",
        "Classic Christian",
        "Contemporary Gospel",
        "Gospel",
        "Christian & Gospel",
        "Praise & Worship",
        "Qawwali",
        "Southern Gospel",
        "Traditional Gospel",
        "Instrumental",
        "March",
        "J-Pop",
        "J-Rock",
        "J-Synth",
        "J-Ska",
        "J-Punk",
        "Jazz",
        "Acid Jazz",
        "Avant-Garde Jazz",
        "Bebop",
        "Big Band",
        "Blue Note",
        "Contemporary Jazz",
        "Cool",
        "Crossover Jazz",
        "Dixieland",
        "Ethio-jazz",
        "Fusion",
        "Gypsy Jazz",
        "Hard Bop",
        "Latin Jazz",
        "Mainstream Jazz",
        "Ragtime",
        "Smooth Jazz",
        "Trad Jazz",
        "K-Pop",
        "Karaoke",
        "Kayokyoku",
        "Latin",
        "Alternativo & Rock Latino",
        "Argentine tango",
        "Baladas y Boleros",
        "Bossa Nova",
        "Brazilian",
        "Contemporary Latin",
        "Cumbia",
        "Flamenco / Spanish Flamenco",
        "Latin Jazz",
        "Nuevo Flamenco",
        "Pop Latino",
        "Portuguese fado",
        "Raíces",
        "Reggaeton y Hip-Hop",
        "Regional Mexicano",
        "Salsa y Tropical",
        "New Age",
        "Environmental",
        "Healing",
        "Meditation",
        "Nature",
        "Relaxation",
        "Travel",
        "Opera",
        "Pop",
        "Adult Contemporary",
        "Britpop",
        "Bubblegum Pop",
        "Chamber Pop",
        "Dance Pop",
        "Dream Pop", 
        "Electro Pop",
        "Orchestral Pop",
        "Pop/Rock",
        "Pop Punk",
        "Power Pop",
        "Soft Rock",
        "Synthpop",
        "Teen Pop",
        "R&B/Soul",
        "Contemporary R&B",
        "Disco",
        "Doo Wop",
        "Funk",
        "Modern Soul",
        "Motown",
        "Neo-Soul",
        "Northern Soul",
        "Psychedelic Soul",
        "Quiet Storm",
        "Soul",
        "Soul Blues",
        "Southern Soul",
        "Reggae",
        "2-Tone",
        "Dancehall",
        "Dub",
        "Roots Reggae",
        "Ska",
        "Rock",
        "Acid Rock",
        "Adult-Oriented Rock",
        "Afro Punk",
        "Adult Alternative",
        "Alternative Rock",
        "American Trad Rock",
        "Anatolian Rock",
        "Arena Rock",
        "Art Rock",
        "Blues-Rock",
        "British Invasion",
        "Cock Rock",
        "Death Metal / Black Metal",
        "Doom Metal",
        "Glam Rock",
        "Gothic Metal",
        "Grind Core",
        "Hair Metal",
        "Hard Rock",
        "Math Metal",
        "Math Rock",
        "Metal",
        "Metal Core",
        "Noise Rock",
        "Jam Bands",
        "Post Punk",
        "Prog-Rock/Art Rock",
        "Progressive Metal",
        "Psychedelic",
        "Rock & Roll",
        "Rockabilly",
        "Roots Rock",
        "Singer/Songwriter",
        "Southern Rock",
        "Spazzcore",
        "Stoner Metal",
        "Surf",
        "Technical Death Metal",
        "Tex-Mex",
        "Time Lord Rock (Trock)",
        "Trash Metal",
        "Singer/Songwriter",
        "Alternative Folk",
        "Contemporary Folk",
        "Contemporary Singer/Songwriter",
        "Indie Folk",
        "Folk-Rock",
        "Love Song",
        "New Acoustic",
        "Traditional Folk",
        "Soundtrack",
        "Foreign Cinema",
        "Movie Soundtrack",
        "Musicals",
        "Original Score",
        "Soundtrack",
        "TV Soundtrack",
        "Spoken Word",
        "Tex-Mex / Tejano",
        "Chicano",
        "Classic",
        "Conjunto",
        "Conjunto Progressive",
        "New Mex",
        "Tex-Mex",
        "Vocal",
        "A cappella",
        "Barbershop",
        "Doo-wop",
        "Gregorian Chant",
        "Standards",
        "Traditional Pop",
        "Vocal Jazz",
        "Vocal Pop",
        "World",
        "Africa",
        "Afro-Beat",
        "Afro-Pop",
        "Asia",
        "Australia",
        "Cajun",
        "Calypso",
        "Caribbean",
        "Carnatic",
        "Celtic",
        "Celtic Folk",
        "Contemporary Celtic",
        "Coupé-décalé",
        "Dangdut",
        "Drinking Songs",
        "Drone",
        "Europe",
        "France",
        "Hawaii",
        "Hindustani",
        "Indian Ghazal",
        "Indian Pop",
        "Japan",
        "Japanese Pop",
        "Klezmer",
        "Mbalax",
        "Middle East",
        "North America",
        "Ode",
        "Piphat",
        "Polka",
        "Soca",
        "South",
        "South America",
        "Traditional Celtic",
        "Worldbeat",
        "Zydeco",
    ]){}, {} %>
    <h6>Description</h6>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :input_html => { class: 'test', :rows => 50 } %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

    <div id="addresses">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
        <%= render 'address_fields', :f => address %>
      <% end %>

    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add address', f, :addresses %>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
 <% f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### essentials_controller.rb

```
class EssentialsController < ApplicationController


  # GET /essentials
  # GET /essentials.json
  def index
   @user_id = current_user.id
  @essentials = Essential.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @essentials }
    end
  end

  # GET /essentials/1
  # GET /essentials/1.json
  def show
    @essential = Essential.find(params[:id])


  end

  # GET /essentials/new
  def new

    @essential = Essential.new
    @essential.addresses.build
 #  3.times { @essential.addresses.build}




  end

  # GET /essentials/1/edit
  def edit

      @essential = Essential.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  # POST /essentials
  # POST /essentials.json
  def create

      @essential = Essential.new(essential_params)
        if @essential.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render :new
        end
     @essential.user_id = current_user.id
     @essential.save

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /essentials/1
  # PATCH/PUT /essentials/1.json
  def update

s
  end

  # DELETE /essentials/1
  # DELETE /essentials/1.json
  def destroy
    @essential = Essential.find(params[:id])
    if @essential.present?
      @essential.destroy
     redirect_to essentials_path, notice: "Post was deleted"

  end

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_essential
      @essential = Essential.find(params[:id])
    end


    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

    def essential_params
      params.require(:essential).permit(
      :band_name, :years_active_start, :country, :studio_albums, :band_members, :genre, :description, :user_id, :years_active_end, addresses_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :url, :essential_id])
    end
end
```

#### schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161120025634) do

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.text     "url",          limit: 65535
    t.integer  "essential_id", limit: 4
  end

  create_table "essentials", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.string   "band_members",       limit: 255
    t.integer  "years_active_end",   limit: 4
    t.integer  "years_active_start", limit: 4
    t.string   "band_name",          limit: 255
    t.string   "country",            limit: 255
    t.string   "studio_albums",      limit: 255
    t.string   "genre",              limit: 255
    t.integer  "user_id",            limit: 4
    t.text     "description",        limit: 65535
  end

  create_table "homes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "index",      limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,   default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                      null: false
    t.string   "first_name",             limit: 255
    t.string   "last_name",              limit: 255
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write

```
<%= render 'address_fields', :f => :address %>
```

and it should just be

```
<%= render 'address_fields', :f => address %>
```

In other words: use the variable given to the surrounding block (not a symbol that happens to have the same name).

Comment: Thank you, that did fix the method error. Now when I click the add address link to add a new field nothing happens. It just brings me back to top of the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a javascript error (since it just executes the default behaviour). Either cocoon is not loaded, either you have some other javascript error: check your console in the browser.

Comment: I will take a look at myjavascript. One thing I have noticed is that my nested-field displays before I have added it. In your demo project that is not the case. Is that more than likely an error on my part or possibly a clue to something else going on?

Comment: That's because you have `@essential.addresses.build` in your controller, which builds an empty address, so it always shows the form. I would presume, if you wrote that in your code, it is what you wanted :)

Comment: I actually got @essential.addresses.build from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238720/cocoon-gem-undefined-method-new-record-for-nilnilclass-on-link-to-remove-as). I was having the same problem and that solution does fix it. I am not entirely sure that is the best solution though.If I remove it I get 'undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass'.

Comment: Ok, I just answered that question. Your code seems ok, and should not have the same error. The `build` builds 1 empty element, so it is shown. If you do not build empty elements, the page should just render fine, and not show empty elements, so it will only add new elements when your user clicks the link. So just removing the `@essential.addresses.build` should still work. Just adding the `build` without fixing the error (on the other answer) will not work. So if it works now, it will keep working. If it does not, it is another error, so please ask a new question.